# How do I make a TBitmap transparent when loading it from a resource

Tags: delphi, transparency, tbitmap

I am trying to load a TBitmap from resources while keeping it transparent. Even with the transparent Property enabled it still looks the same.

What I tried to do:

```
procedure TMovie.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 BitMap1 : TBitMap;
begin
  BitMap1 := TBitMap.Create;

  BitMap1.Transparent := TRUE;
  BitMap1.TransparentColor := clBlack;

  try
    BitMap1.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'Bitmap_2');
    Star_2.Picture.Assign(Bitmap1);
  finally
    BitMap1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What happens when you don't set `TransparentColor`? It's possible that the color you're identifying is not pure black, which would cause that line to keep things from working.

Comment: @Ken White I tried to not set the Transparent Color at all and checked the rbg value of the background. It is pure black.

Comment: After the call to `LoadFromResourceName`, what is the value of the bitmap's `PixelFormat`?

Comment: @Ken White The pixel format is set to pfDevice. The default one.

Comment: try changing it to pf32bit before loading the image.

Comment: @Ken White I tried that and it unfortunately did not resolve the problem. I also tried other values, but they to gave the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to invert transparency properties as follow:

```pascal
procedure TMovie.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 BitMap1 : TBitMap;
begin
  BitMap1 := TBitMap.Create;
  
  try
    BitMap1.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'Bitmap_2');

    BitMap1.Transparent := TRUE;
    BitMap1.TransparentColor := clBlack;

    Star_2.Picture.Assign(Bitmap1);
  finally
    BitMap1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I did that and even tried a picture with a different background color but the result did not change. The pictures still are not transparent.

Comment: @Codex are you sure the pixels you want are actually pure-black, and not an off-black? Do you have the same problem with other colors, like clFuschia?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I did check, and it is pure black. I also tried with RBG(0,0,0) to see id it would make a difference. It did not.